# Incorrect tags when posting on meta

Tags: bug, tags, android-app

When posting a question to Meta via the Android app, I'm not getting the tags specifically for Meta - rather the tags for Stack Overflow. It almost looks like it's not attempting to post the question to Meta at all.

For example, there is an [android-app](/questions/tagged/android-app) tag. This is what I'm getting in the search results in the mobile app:

[image: android tags from SO]

But this is what I get on Meta desktop:

[image: android tags from MSO]

Comment: Working fine in iOS app, so it's not the API.

Comment: Working fine for me. I think you might have ended up on the Stack Overflow site by mistake or something. http://i.stack.imgur.com/dqk7A.png

Comment: I picked meta from the sites dropdown list. Strange! I did have a  issue this morning where the app just didn't load. Maybe connected. I'll uninstall /reinstall and see if I can repro

Comment: Same issue on my separate Nexus 7 (2012) tablet...

Comment: It appears the app gets sort of "locked in" to whatever site you last tried to use. As in, it doesn't appear to pay attention to what site is in the site selector drop-down at all. It always uses the site that was selected when you hit the ask question button.

Answer (score 3):

As of v1.0.82 (beta)<sup>or somewhere before that</sup>, it has been fixed (<s>with minor issue</s>): the tag list is now *following the selected site*.

[image: ask on SO] [image: change site to Meta]

[image: after choosing Meta] [image: tags on Meta]

However, the search result is cached, so if you perform a tag search and then changing site, the previous result will be shown *until you make a change on the search query*. (It's [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) from [Kasra's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234182/241919))

[image: ask on SO] [image: tags on SO]
[image: change site to Meta] [image: after choosing Meta]
[image: tags from SO cached] [image: tags are being updated due to changing on the search query]