# Changing site that you ask to does not change the underlying site you submit to on mobile app

Tags: bug, status-norepro, android-app

If I go to StackOverflow on my mobile app, and I write a question if I change the site (say to Programmers or what have you) it seems to preserve the tags you can select.

I fear you haven't actually changed site. I've not tried to submit after doing that (I can never select the correct tags for the Q anyway). But I don't think this is right.

How the  reproduce:

1. Go to a site, called Site A, on the android mobile app.
2. Ask a question, but change the site to Site B, via the drop down selector.
3. Go to select tags.
4. Expected: The tags from Site B.
   Result: The tags from Site A.

Comment: If I have the draft, and come back to it, it picks up the correct site. It's more that I'm offered the wrong set of tags after a site change.

Comment: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/4742/3804

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229315/incorrect-tags-when-posting-on-meta (my answer seems to reinforce Kasra's answer here)

Answer (score 3):

It does change it. It just doesn't reset the tags. It'll give you an error when you attempt to post if the tags aren't real ones on the newly chosen site. We chose not to reset the tags field when changing between sites because then an accidental tap on the site switcher could lead to losing your tags, which would be a bad experience.

Comment: I never realized that it's impossible to create a new tag via the app. Is that just an app limitation or an API limitation?

Comment: @StevenV Probably both. The mobile website doesn't allow tag creation either. It tells you to visit the full version of the site.

Comment: Korea, I've not experienced that. Only that if I started on stackoverflow, and change to rpg stackexchange I can only access stackoverflow's tags.

Comment: Do you know if this has changed/checked my last comment?